# Independence of tigonometric functions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trigonometry, independence

Are contineous functions

$y=\cos^2 \ (x) ; y = cos(2x) ; y = 1$

linearly dependent or not?

I think that they are, but I cannot explain it in formula.

Generally when we are solving such questions in class, we have same instruction, but we take vectors, such as:

a = (3;1;2) b = (9;-4;2) c = (-1;2;2)

Then it is easy to look for dependance because we can just create a system.

$a= w_1*b+w_2*c$

Now we can just solve the system,

\begin{cases} 9w_1  -w_2 = 3\\ -4w_1  +2w_2 = 1 \\ 2w_1  +2w_2 = 2 \end{cases}

And we find out that $w_1 = 1/2; w_2 = 3/2$

So there is dependance.
How do I do the same thing with trigonometric functions?

Comment: $\cos 2(x)$ doesn't mean anything. Did you want to write $\cos(2x)$?

Comment: oh yes, sorry, corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we know that

$cos(2x)=2cos^2(x)-1$

or
$cos(2x)-2cos^2(x)+1=0$.

so the three functions are linearly dependent since there exist 
$(a,b,c)=(1,-2,1)\neq(0,0,0)$ such that

$a\times cos(2x)+b\times cos^2(x)+c\times 1=0$

Comment: Is there any possibility to elaborate. I can see that the formula is a direct reason why they are dependent, but it doesen't look like a valid thing to write as an answer.

Comment: @Moontego read again the answer

Comment: Thanks, now i'm getting it! Now it looks like the one we did in the class!